# Putting two scripts together (actionscript)

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have two scripts I wish I could make a game with, but can't seem to make them work together.
Both of them are working great individually. I was hoping maybe someone could guide me into putting them together.

http://ifile.it/i6scean
Here is the first.

http://ifile.it/h02wez5 This is the other. It's for the enemy to follow the player once he's in a particular range.

If that can help, the objective of the game is for the player to get to the opposite end of the "maze" without being hit by the enemy.

I also had trouble figuring out how to do the collision system, but I guess I could search this in the other questions.

Thanks a lot,

Mathieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just placing the second code below the first code (and renaming player_mc to player) works fine... Just make sure you also put the "enemy" movie clip in your library on your first project.... And get rid of the startDrag stopDrag code if you don't want the player to be able to click and drag the character.. For collision detection look into the "hitTest" function... Very simple stuff... put it in under the _root.onEnterFrame code so it's constantly being checked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm quite a beginner to actionscript and hope to learn a lot :)

Comment: Any idea how they could not be able to go through walls?

Comment: You could set their initial x and y value to be not on the walls and then if they hit the wall change the direction they are moving in.